# Find the property's scope within class

Tags: php, reflection

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function list()
    {
        foreach ($this as $property => $value)
        {
            if (is_public($this->$property))
                echo 'public: ';
            else if (is_protected($this->$property))
                echo 'protected: ';
            echo "$property => $value" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    protected $Size = 4;
    protected $Type = 4;
    public $SubT = 1;
    public $UVal = NULL;
}

$CC = new ChildClass;
$CC->list();
```

Comment: What's the question? How to [actually use the Reflectionclases provided to you?](http://www.php.net/reflection)

Comment: Is the reflection class the only way to do this? Why is there no direct functions available for this?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense for a function to exist.  The function would get the value of the variable.  Unless it was something like: `is_public($this, 'propertyName')`...  But even that won't make sense since there are magic methods (`__get` namely) that can simulate those properties.  So reflection is the best way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ReflectionProperty`, it's possible. You could create a helper function if you want to make it less verbose:

```
<?php
function P($obj, $name)
{
  return new ReflectionProperty($obj, $name);
}

class Foo
{
  public $a;

  public function __construct()
  {
    foreach (array_keys(get_object_vars($this)) as $name)
    {
      if (P($this, $name)->isPublic())
      {
        echo "Public\n";
      }
    }
  }
}

new Foo();

?>
```